# How can I get the same results of this Nodejs code in php?

Tags: php, node.js

Nodejs code:

```
var tagVal= "Bobs Basement Records";      
var bufname = Buffer.from(tagVal,'utf8');
console.log(bufname);
console.log(bufname.toString());
console.log(bufname.toString('base64'));
```

Results:

```
<Buffer 42 6f 62 73 20 42 61 73 65 6d 65 6e 74 20 52 65 63 6f 72 64 73>
Bobs Basement Records
Qm9icyBCYXNlbWVudCBSZWNvcmRz
```

EDIT:
The results in PHP is different:

```
<?php
$name = "Bobs Basement Records";

$bufName = bin2hex($name);

echo $bufName."\n";
echo hex2bin($bufName)."\n";
echo base64_encode($bufName)."\n";

?>
```

Results of PHP code:

```
426f627320426173656d656e74205265636f726473
Bobs Basement Records
NDI2ZjYyNzMyMDQyNjE3MzY1NmQ2NTZlNzQyMDUyNjU2MzZmNzI2NDcz
```

See the result of:

```
console.log(bufname.toString('base64'));
Qm9icyBCYXNlbWVudCBSZWNvcmRz
```

Is not the same as in PHP:

```
echo base64_encode($bufName)."\n";
NDI2ZjYyNzMyMDQyNjE3MzY1NmQ2NTZlNzQyMDUyNjU2MzZmNzI2NDcz
```

This means that the results of Buffer.from

```
var bufname = Buffer.from(tagVal,'utf8');
```

is not the same as bin2hex

```
$bufName = bin2hex($name);
```

Any idea about this?.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some php code?

Comment: Use echo `base64_encode($bufname);` for converting string to base64

Comment: I tried `bin2hex()` and  `unpack()` but they don't give the same results of the `Buffer.from()`

Comment: @pulzarraider the thing is I need to convert the string to `<Buffer 42 6f 62 73 20 42 61 73 65 6d 65 6e 74 20 52 65 63 6f 72 64 73>` before using `base64_encode()`

Comment: I have added two possible solutions. What you need is ASCII code of each character in hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Here are two (of many possible) solutions:

With array:

```php
$tagVal= "Bobs Basement Records";

$charCodes = unpack("C*", $tagVal);
echo '<Buffer';
foreach ($charCodes as $charCode) {
    echo ' '.dechex($charCode);
}
echo '>'."\n";

echo $tagVal."\n";
echo base64_encode($tagVal)."\n";
```

Without using array.

```php
$tagVal= "Bobs Basement Records";

echo '<Buffer';
$length = strlen($tagVal);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    echo ' '.dechex(ord($tagVal[$i]));
}
echo '>'."\n";

echo $tagVal."\n";
echo base64_encode($tagVal)."\n";
```

Output:

```
<Buffer 42 6f 62 73 20 42 61 73 65 6d 65 6e 74 20 52 65 63 6f 72 64 73>
Bobs Basement Records
Qm9icyBCYXNlbWVudCBSZWNvcmRz
```

Comment: `dechex()` and `bin2hex()` do not give the results as `Buffer.from()`

Comment: I will add some PHP to the Q to show you the problem.

Comment: @En.Wagdi your're wrong. If you convert binary data to hexadecimal format, it will give you different result. That's what you have done in `$bufName = bin2hex($name); base64_encode($bufName)`. PHP is not NodeJs. In PHP you doesn't need the buffer to work with the string data.

Comment: what do you mean by "In PHP you don't need the buffer to work with the string data", What happens in Nodejs code? Isn't it converting to hex?

Comment: Hexadecimal format is just a visual representation of data. See this table as a demonstration: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/2560px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png 
Char "B" has the number 66 in the ASCII table in decimal format, but it can be also written as 42 in hexadecimal format. If you send the buffer with string data to console.log in NodeJs, you will see the hexadecimal output of the chars, but the char is not changed., it's still "B".

Comment: @En.Wagdi can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that your PHP code uses UTF8 encoding:

```
<?php

print_r(utf8_encode("Bobs Basement Records") . "\n");
print_r(base64_encode(utf8_encode("Bobs Basement Records")) . "\n");
```

See

[image]